# JUnit: TestRunner initializationError

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I build the tests using gradle.build, used **junit 4.12** and **hamcrest 1.3**

And used command ->

```
java -Xmx1024m -classpath .:build/libs/loklak_server-all.jar:build/classes/test org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.loklak.harvester.TestRunner
```

This is the directory structure of the project

```
(root project)
   |__ build
         |__ classes
                 |__ main/org/loklak/harvester
                                           |__ TwitterScraper.class
                 |__ test/org/loklak/harvester
                                           |__ TestRunner.class
                                           |__ TwitterScraper.class
   |__ src/org/loklak/harvester/TwitterScraper.java
   |__ test/org/loklak/harvester
                             |__ TwitterScraperTest.java
                             |__ TestRunner.java
```

I am getting error ->

```
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.loklak.harvester.TestRunner)
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.createRequest(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:118)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
package org.loklak.harvester;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

import org.loklak.harvester.TwitterScraperTest;
import org.loklak.harvester.TwitterScraper;

public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TwitterScraperTest.class);

        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) 
            System.out.println(failure.toString());

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }

}
```

I am able to run **TwitterScraperTest.java** separately without any error.
I have gone through all the Stack Overflow questions, but couldn't fix this.
What I am missing?

Comment: This is not a test class a test class should have a method annotated with `@Test` instead of a main method, so instead of `public static void main(String[] args)` try `@Test public void myTestNameGoesHere(){ ...`

Comment: Though I'm not sure HOW to do it directly using the TestRunner (`JUnitCore.runClasses`) as you did... Try the suggestion above and see what happens. Also if you are using Gradle you should run it with grade, not pure java.

Comment: @Jorge Campos i am doing something like in this link, the way you are suggesting, it is working. But I need to use testrunner https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_basic_usage.htm

Comment: hmmm, so show your `TwitterScraperTest` class maybe the problem is with it.